# USBView Compile Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, usb

I just downloaded the [USBView sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039), and I'm getting a cryptic error when compiling with Visual Studio 2010.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: usbview, Configuration: Win8 Debug Win32 ------ 
1>Build started 10/5/2012 11:58:11 AM.
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(518,5):
error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset
(WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.0) is not installed or invalid. Please
make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.16
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any thoughts or ideas to resolve this would be appreciated.  I'm using Windows 7, 32-bit.

Comment: This similar problem might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245771/sharing-a-c-solution-between-visual-studio-2010-and-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by installing Visual Studio 2012 Express and recommended components, removing the offending line from the Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets file (double-clicked error message), and compiling as Release.