# How to make a c++ project run on a different PCs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lapack, blas, armadillo

I developed a small c++ program in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows7, 64bit (let's call it PC1). On that pc it runs fine!

Since I didn't have a versioning control system like SVN at hand, I copied ALL the project data (the exact folder structure, DLLs, source files, project files...) to a usb stick and moved it to another computer.
On that other engine there's Visual Studio 2010 on Windows7, 64bit (PC2).
So I just changed the platform toolset to v100 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245771/sharing-a-c-solution-between-visual-studio-2010-and-11).

I successfully compiled the project on PC2 (clean, build) and wanted to run the exe, but the command prompt stayed empty.
I then tried to debug and added a breakpoint at the very first line of main - which wasn't reached, the command prompt was still empty.

Ok, a usb stick is certainly not the most secure solution for data storage, so I gave it another try and moved it again - the problem remains.

Visual Studio's output on PC2 is the same as on PC1, so I couldn't find any anomalies there.

Yeah, there might be many error sources, so where can I start?

And how can I get a more verbose output for troubleshooting?

Or is this even a common phenomenon (perhaps due to different VS versions) and there's an simple way fix it?

Comment: If it's a simple project, have you tried to create a new project on PC2 and just add the existing files. Does that work?

Comment: First, use the same version of VS on both machines if you are copying project files around.

Comment: try running the built exe on PC2 under dependency walker to see what it's trying to do (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: you might try making the project and solution files on VS2010 from scratch, then upgrade them using VS2012... in other words, reverse the direction you're trying to move your project files.

Comment: You are trying to use 2012 version files in 2010 version? Something doesn't add up... I don't think the 2010 version is future-compatible to all future versions. That might be the problem.

Comment: If it is a smaller project, you could try creating a new project on the 2010 machine, manually adding the source/header files, possibly updating the project config, and seeing if it builds/runs.  This would eliminate the possibility that 2010 is ignoring something 2012-specific in the 2012 project files.  Also, make absolutely sure you have a compatible MSVCRT run time installed (normally this should give a 'side-by-side-configuration incorrect' error, but if you're linked to an almost-but-not-quite-compatible version, very odd things can happen.

Comment: Hi, I took your advices into account and created a brand new project on PC2, VS2010. I exactly followed this guide: http://frozenhamster.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/lapack-on-windows-with-visual-studion-2010/
The problem remains the same: the console window is empty, no prompt, just a blinking cursor and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution, but at least I'm a tiny step ahead:

In my last comment I wrote:

> I took your advices into account and created a brand new project on PC2, VS2010. I exactly followed this guide: http://frozenhamster.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/lapack-on-windows-with-visual-studion-2010/

That didn't work either, so I removed I "out-commented" everything except for a single cout. Voila, that worked!
But as soon as I make use of the desired Armadillo (LAPACK and BLAS), the project compils but does not run.

What's going wrong here?
I don't get any compiler errors!